# Соединение регулярок с помощью I

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не понимаю, почему по отдельности работает, а если соединить, то работать не будет?

Надо удалить слова, в которых есть повторяющиеся буквы

```
echo preg_replace('#([a-z]+)\1[a-z]+#', '', 'wword word'); //работает
echo '<br>';
echo preg_replace('#[a-z]+([a-z]+)\1#', '', 'word wordd'); //работает
echo '<br>';
echo preg_replace('#(([a-z]+)\1([a-z]+)|[a-z]+([a-z]+)\1)#', '', 'wword word'); //не работает
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что первая группа в третьей регулярке это

```
([a-z]+)\1([a-z]+)|[a-z]+([a-z]+)\1
```

так как у вас там скобки вокруг всего выражения стоят.

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('#([a-z]+)\1[a-z]+#', '', 'wword word'); //работает
echo "\n";
echo preg_replace('#[a-z]+([a-z]+)\1#', '', 'word wordd'); //работает
echo "\n";
echo preg_replace('#([a-z]+)\1[a-z]+|[a-z]+([a-z]+)\2#', '', 'wword word'); //работает
```

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0b8c2279e8deae138d53bebd43087d1456740475

Comment: почему скобки не нужны вокруг всей регулярки?

Comment: @DivMan, если вы поставите скобки вокруг всей регулярки, это будет отдельная группа

Comment: Можно пользоваться незахватывающей группой: `(?:  ... )`

Answer (score 1):

Номерные захватывающие подмаски (группы) нумеруются в порядке их очереди в регулярном выражении, слева направо.

```
(([a-z]+)\1([a-z]+)|[a-z]+([a-z]+)\1)
|| - #1    |              |
 | - #2    |              |
           | - #3         |
                          | - #4
```

Для удаления слов, в которых повторяются буквы, можно использовать регулярное выражение без группы альтернатив с помощью

```
echo preg_replace('#[a-z]*([a-z]+)\1[a-z]*#', '', 'wword ok wordd');
// =>  ok 
// С поддержкой Юникода
echo preg_replace('#\p{L}*(\p{L}+)\1\p{L}*#u', '', 'слослон из зоопарка');
// => из
```

См. демо(https://ideone.com/HGl7k8).

**Описание**

- `[a-z]*` - 0 и более букв (`\p{L}` найдет любую букву Юникода)
- `([a-z]+)` - захватывающая подмаска (группа) №1, 1  и более букв
- `\1` - обратная ссылка на текст в подмаске №1
- `[a-z]*` - 0 и более букв

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/BOFali/1)